# Map null column as 0 in a legacy database (JPA)

Tags: database, jpa, null, legacy, playframework

Using Play! framework and it's JPASupport class I have run into a problem with a legacy database.

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_catalog")
public class ProductCatalog extends JPASupport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer product_catalog;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="upper_catalog")
    public ProductCatalog upper_catalog;

    public String name;
}
```

Some product catalogs don't have an upper catalog, and this is referenced as 0 in a legacy database. If I supply the upper_catalog as NULL, then expectedly JPA inserts a NULL value to that database column.
How could I force the null values to be 0 when writing to the database and the other way around when reading from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any easy way of achieving what you want with JPA directly (and there are great chance that even if you find a way that works with basic operation like save or load, that it will not work with more complex use case, like complex criteria / hql, none standard fetching mode, etc)

So i would do that :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_catalog")
public class ProductCatalog extends JPASupport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer product_catalog;

    @Column(name="upper_catalog")
    public Long upper_catalog_id;

    public String name;

    public ProductCatalog getUpperCatalog() {
       if (upper_catalog_id == 0)
         return null;

       return ProductCatalog.findById(upper_catalog_id);
    }

    public void setUpperCatalog(ProductCatalog pc) {
       if (pc == null) {
         upper_catalog_id = 0;
       }
       else {
         if (pc.id == null) {
            // option 1. a bit like a cascade
            pc.save();
            // option 2. if you consider passing a transient entity is not valid
            throw new RuntimeException("transient entity " + pc.toString());
         }
         upper_catalog_id = pc.id;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! Just had to change the Long to Integer (some Play! configuration?).

What is the meaning of @Transient in this case - I didn't add this and all my tests for this class seem to pass fine.

Comment: @Transient is understood by the JPA provider as : "do not manage this field (don't save it to database))". I forgot that with play! @Transient is only needed on fields. I used Long because it is the default play! type for id, but use whatever you wish

Comment: I've just re-read the code, and you should be careful to call the setter only with persistent ProductCatalog (with an id) otherwise it won't work. (Perhap's you should add this test at the beginning of the method: if pc.id is null, then persist pc).

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

- Use a primitive data type as `Id` (i.e. `int` instead of `Integer`)
- If you are using Hibernate as JPA provider, use a `CustomType` to do the conversion